# PIL / Easy Thumbnails Missing Dependencies Django

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library, easy-thumbnails

I ported a web application to another machine, but am having a problem getting [django easy thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) setup on another team member's machine (mac osx 10.6 snow leopard). I know it requires PIL, but am having problems getting it and perhaps its dependencies set up on the machine.

I read [this post](http://arcoleo.org/dsawiki/Wiki.jsp?page=How%20to%20Install%20Libjpeg%20on%20Mac) detailing how to install libjpeg on a mac, but still did not have luck. Afterwards, I tried to uninstall PIL and instead use Pillow, but still does not work:

```
(newenv)wsp049614wss:site-packages Admin$ pip uninstall pil
  Successfully uninstalled PIL

(newenv)wsp049614wss:site-packages Admin$ pip install pillow
Downloading/unpacking pillow
  Downloading Pillow-2.2.1.zip (2.2MB): 2.2MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pillow

--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      Pillow 2.2.1
platform     darwin 2.7.5 (default, Oct 27 2013, 12:25:46)
             [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support not available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
*** WEBP support not available
*** WEBPMUX support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What am I missing? How can I get easy_thumbnails to work? I did not change anything in the codebase, and easy-thumbnails works on other machines. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: What isn't working with easy thumbnails?

Comment: The `thumbnail_url` tag is not working nor are the images being resized and saved. The images exist in the filesystem and I can load them using `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ instance.image }}`. Easy thumbnails doesn't seem to be working at all since none of the images are being resized and saved. Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh no - you have the dreaded libjpeg Snow leopard issue. Basically your standard pip install of PIL doesn't work, it messes up the libjpeg C lib. There are a million blogs on this issue, [this](http://www.brambraakman.com/blog/comments/installing_pil_in_snow_leopard_jpeg_resync_to_restart_error/) one worked for me, but you'll have to hunt around trying out various fixes.